# How can I loop through a stdObject's array without raising PHP notices/warnings?

Tags: php, foreach, warnings, e-notices

I have the following stdObject obtained thru cURL / json_decode():

```
stdClass Object
(
    [response] => stdClass Object
        (
            [status] => OK
            [num_elements] => 1030
            [start_element] => 0
            [results] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [publisher] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [num_elements] => 1030
                            [results] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1234
                                            [weight] => 4444
                                            [name] => Pub 1
                                            [member_id] => 1
                                            [state] => active
                                            [code] => 
                                        )

                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1235
                                            [weight] => 4444
                                            [name] => Pub 2
                                            [member_id] => 2
                                            [state] => active
                                            [code] => 
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [dbg_info] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [instance] => instance1.server.com
                    [slave_hit] => 1
                    [db] => db1.server.com
                    [reads] => 3
                    [read_limit] => 100
                    [read_limit_seconds] => 60
                    [writes] => 0
                    [write_limit] => 60
                    [write_limit_seconds] => 60
                    [awesomesauce_cache_used] => 
                    [count_cache_used] => 
                    [warnings] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [time] => 70.440053939819
                    [start_microtime] => 1380833763.4083
                    [version] => 1.14
                    [slave_lag] => 0
                    [member_last_modified_age] => 2083072
                )

        )

)
```

I'm looping through it in order to obtain each result's ID:

```
foreach ($result->response->results->publisher->results as $object) {
    $publishers .= $object->id.",";
}
```

And although the code is working fine, PHP is rising the following notices/warnings:

> PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/script.php on line 1
>   PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/script.php on line 1
>   PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/script.php on line 1

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible you have set the second parameter `$assoc` in json_decode() to `true`? Like this:

```
$result = json_decode($json_from_curl, true);
```

Thereby, getting back $result with all stdClass Objects converted to associative array.

EDIT: 
If the `$result` you are getting is indeed an associative array, then we should treat it as such. Try replacing your `foreach` with this:

```
foreach ($result['response']['results']['publisher']['results'] as $arr) {
    $publishers .= $arr['id'] . ",";
}
```

EDIT2: 
From my own testing based on your code, everything should be working correctly. The notices/warnings should not occur. Perhaps some other code not shown in your question is causing it.

Comment: Hello @abstr and thank you for your answer! Your solution looks like a great alternative but sadly the json_decode is called inside a general function which is used throughout the application. Therefore any change would require to make lots of modifications to the rest of the application. Strangely, this is the only loop that's throwing PHP notices and I would like to understand a bit more why it's happening. Best regards!

Comment: You were right, the problem was caused by an undocumented "feature" of the API I was using. Thanks for the great response!